# Can't test NServicebus Message Handlers with Messages which implement generics

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, reflection, nservicebus

I'm using:

- nservicebus 2.0.0.0
- nservicebus.Testing 2.0.0.0
- VS2010
- nUnit
- .NET 4.0
- c#

I'm using the nservicebus.Testing namespace which nservicebus provides for testing IMessage handlers.

My tests throw this error when invoking the IMessage handler:

> System.InvalidOperationException :
>   Late bound operations cannot be
>   performed on types or methods for
>   which ContainsGenericParameters is
>   true.

This error goes away and the tests run fine if I remove a reference in the test project to an assembly which contains IMessages which implement generics.

**NOTE** that the Handler I'm testing is not handling the generics messages, the mere presence of the generics message in the bin folder is causing the error.

**I would like however to be able to test handlers for IMessages which implement generics, is this possible?**

cheers

Comment: can you perhaps provide the code for the message handler + the message implementation that seems to be causing the fault when included as a reference?

Comment: Where does this exception actually come from? A stack trace would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the NServiceBus testing library makes use of the same assembly type scanning logic as NServiceBus in general. In order to prevent scanning the problematic assembly, call Test.Initialize(params Assembly[] assemblies);

All that being said, it isn't recommended to have messages that make use of generics.

Comment: cool, thanks udi. Yeah, I hear you about not recommending it, in true distributed style I don't "own" the messages though, but I can talk to the owner. Regardless though, could you confirm for me, are you saying that I can't test a message handler using .Testing which implements generics at all?

Comment: Haven't checked that, but as a philosophy NServiceBus intentionally doesn't support things which aren't recommended - we don't want to make it easy to make architectural mistakes.

Comment: understood, though it would be good to know what is and what is not actually supported. It seems to me that nservicebus runs absolutely fine with generic messages, yet they can't be tested. surely it would make more sense to warn the user at the point of usage...? it's like argument exceptions, it's good practice to throw them right at the top of the method, it just makes sense.